# Lambda expressions without input

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I saw one program that was about synchrony and using threads. In one part of the program, I saw this lambda expression and I got confused.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  Thread.Sleep(100);
  progressBar1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
  {
    progressBar1.Value = i;
    listBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
  }));
}
```

My question is, why this lambda expression doesn't have any input argument?

Comment: Threads (by default) doesn't get any input argument(implicitly) also doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

In the *Control.BeginInvoke* method's description there is written:

```
// Summary:
//     Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the 
//     thread that the control'sunderlying handle was created on.
//
// Parameters:
//   method:
//     A delegate to a method that takes no parameters.
```

From the [Action Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) MS article:

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and does not return a
>   value.

Answer (score 1):

The goal here is to execute some statements which access the UI on the UI thread. The action doesn't need any input (`i`, `progressBar1` and `listBox1` are captured) and doesn't have an output, only side effects (modifying the UI).